# WCF - Error: Cannot obtain Metadata

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-security

When I try to run my application from the WCF Test Client I receive the following error:

> Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from http://localhost:53867/MyAPI.svc If this is a Windows (R) Communication Foundation service to which you have access, please check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the specified address.
>   For help enabling metadata publishing, please refer to the MSDN documentation at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455.WS-Metadata Exchange Error
>   URI: http://localhost:53867/MyAPI.svc
>   Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://localhost:53867/MyAPI.svc'.
>   Content Type application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 was not supported by service http://localhost:53867/MyAPI.svc.
>   The client and service bindings may be mismatched.
>   The remote server returned an error: (415) Unsupported Media Type.HTTP GET Error
>   URI: http://localhost:53867/MyAPI.svc
>   The HTML document does not contain Web service discovery information.

Here is some of my web.config:

```
    <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
        <assemblies>
            <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
        </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <membership defaultProvider="CustomMembershipProvider">
        <providers>
            <clear/>
            <add name="CustomMembershipProvider" type="Namespace.Models.MyMembershipProvider" />
        </providers>
    </membership>
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="MembershipBinding">
                <security mode ="Message">
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="MyServiceBehavior">
                <serviceCredentials>
                    <userNameAuthentication
                    userNamePasswordValidationMode="MembershipProvider"
                    membershipProviderName="CustomMembershipProvider" />
                </serviceCredentials>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

I've no idea what could be causing this? My Membership Provider is in that location and it has the correct namespace.

Comment: Have you tried going to that url and seeing if you get a specific error from the page?  Browsing to the URL of the service has saved me a lot of time when trying to debug config errors.

Comment: I don't see any endpoints defined in your config?

Comment: It's 4.0 [simplified configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee530014.aspx)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the name attribute from

```
   <behavior name="MyServiceBehavior">
```

and from

```
   <binding name="MembershipBinding">
```

and add serviceMetadata element

```
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior>
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
                <serviceCredentials>
                <userNameAuthentication
                    userNamePasswordValidationMode="MembershipProvider"
                    membershipProviderName="CustomMembershipProvider" />
                </serviceCredentials>

            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
```

Comment: Removing the name attribute from the behavior element worked for me. Thanks,