# Configuration of WCF Service using wsHttpBinding

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, wcf-security

I'm having trouble setting a WCF Service using [`wsHttpBinding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/wcf/security-of-wshttpbinding) and Https base address.

The real issue is when defining the mex, in the Client test WCF:

Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from 
https://localhost:8722/Design_Time_Addresses/_20180420_WcfServiceLibraryTest/Service1/mex 
If this is a Windows (R) Communication Foundation service to which you have access, please check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the specified address.
For help enabling metadata publishing, please refer to the MSDN documentation at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455.

The App.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="NewBehavior0"> <!-- Error: Cannot optain metadata -->
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
            </behavior>

            <behavior name="NewBehavior1"> <!-- Error: Cannot Find Cert -->
              <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
              <serviceCredentials>
                <serviceCertificate  findValue="BadThumbprint" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint"  storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My"/>
              </serviceCredentials>
            </behavior>

            <behavior name="NewBehavior2"> <!-- Error: Cannot optain metadata -->
              <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
              <serviceCredentials>
                <serviceCertificate  findValue="GoodThumbprint" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint"  storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My"/>
              </serviceCredentials>
            </behavior>             
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="wsHTTPBindingConf">
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <!--<message clientCredentialType="None" />-->
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="NewBehavior0" name="_20180420_WcfServiceLibraryTest.Service1">
            <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHTTPBindingConf"
          name="WCFEndpoint" contract="_20180420_WcfServiceLibraryTest.IService1">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          name="mexEndPoint" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
            <host>
                <baseAddresses>
                    <add baseAddress="https://localhost:8722/Design_Time_Addresses/_20180420_WcfServiceLibraryTest/Service1/" />
                </baseAddresses>
            </host>
        </service>
    </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Reading SO and trying every things I found I have try a lot config. But none show a progress worth of mentioning. And look more like, I have no idea. 
What is the correct configuration to make the most basic Ws work(Compile + testable in SoapUi) with wsHttpBinding?

Comment: None Https binding fail with an https based adress. And every Https binding get rejected.

Comment: Did you try `WCF Service Configuration Editor` (from `Tools` menu) or by right click on `App.config` file and select `Edit WCF Configuration`?

Comment: Do you have a cert on your local machine?

Comment: @Tim, Yes A try with both real certificate, and one from the internal PKI.

Comment: @HemidAbbasov, at first I used the tool interface the I read the doc and try to craft it my self. Honestly this is the 6th project create from scratch trying to figure it out.

Comment: @Tim, Using `<serviceCertificate` to choose the right cert using foot print. With a wrong foot print I got an error message about can't find cert. with a good footprint I have the same error : Cannot optain metadata.

Comment: Editded with behavior with certificate I tryed.

Comment: Without the base address and the mex endpoint, have you tried to check if the metadata can be retrieved as such using <address>?wsdl ?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's possibly because the mex `bindingConfiguration=""` is set to an empty string?
Try removing this, or setting it to a Binding.

If the default `mexHttpBinding` doesn't work, try changing it to `wsHttpBinding`. Here is a sample [Custom Secure Metadata Endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/custom-secure-metadata-endpoint) that might help. It says:

> In many of the other samples, the metadata endpoint uses the default `mexHttpBinding`, which is not secure. Here the metadata is secured using `WSHttpBinding` with Message security. In order for metadata clients to retrieve this metadata, they must be configured with a matching binding.

The WCF Test client will need to be configured for the different binding, but I think it will configure itself automatically.

```
<services>   
    <service name="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples.CalculatorService"  
             behaviorConfiguration="CalculatorServiceBehavior">  
     <!-- use base address provided by host -->  
     <endpoint address=""  
       binding="wsHttpBinding"  
       bindingConfiguration="Binding2"  
       contract="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples.ICalculator" />  
     <endpoint address="mex"  
       binding="wsHttpBinding"  
       bindingConfiguration="Binding1"  
       contract="IMetadataExchange" />  
     </service>  
 </services>  
 <bindings>  
   <wsHttpBinding>  
     <binding name="Binding1">  
       <security mode="Message">  
         <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" />  
       </security>  
     </binding>  
     <binding name="Binding2">  
       <reliableSession inactivityTimeout="00:01:00" enabled="true" />  
       <security mode="Message">  
         <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" />  
       </security>  
     </binding>  
   </wsHttpBinding>  
 </bindings>
```

Answer (score 0):

The mex endpoint is wrong. That is the reason for the issue. The following link has complete details regarding the same.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-publish-metadata-for-a-service-using-a-configuration-file

Comment: That's not a lot of information you gave here. What is wrong ? point 7 of the documentation says that `mexHttpsBinding` is valid. the other properties are valid. not that exemple show http not https. if you remove the s in binding and addess to make them http it works. When http is switch to https  error is throw on adress not containning https link. when the https link is added. everything die.

Comment: @xdtTransform Actually my wording was wrong, I meant that 'mex endpoint could be the reason for the issue', but i wrote it is the reason for the issue. I never had enough time to go through it. I have one more link on stackoverflow which addresses similar issue, please go through this once. "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10192824/wcf-error-cannot-obtain-metadata". Not sure that helps but just trying to help. I'm on deadline... so could really through the issue.